# Visual Studio 2012 cannot connect to BizTalk Adapter service on a remote machine

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2012, biztalk-services

I have successfully tested Windows Azure BizTalk Services and on-premise SQL LOB hybrid integration using my local Visual Studio environment. I wanted to move my Adapter service to my dev standalone IIS server. So, I installed the BizTalk Adapter Service runtime on a Windows 2012R2 server successfully. I opened my Visual Studio 2012 as admin and tried to connect to the service by going to Server Explorer > BizTalk Adapter Services and right clicking Add BizTalk Adapter Service menu item. After entering the URL http://myappserver:8080/BAService/ManagementService.svc/ I get the following error.

While spending lot of time searching and reading Microsoft documentation, I understand that Windows authentication is set up in the IIS for this service. So, I tried through the browser. My Visual studio machine is not domain joined as the dev IIS machine. So, I was prompted for login. I was able to access http://myappserver:8080/BAService/ManagementService.svc URL by providing my IIS machine local admin user credentials. Did anybody run into this issue? My broader question is, how do I deploy this BizTalk Service solution to production. There is no guidance on this at all from Microsoft.

> ---
>
> Unable to connect to the specified BizTalk Adapter Service. Please check the service URL including the scheme (http/https), server name and port.
>
> ---
>
> Exception Code: Unauthorized
>
> 401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.
>
> Server Error
>
> 401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.
>
> You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the
>   credentials that you supplied.
>
> Stack Trace: System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an
>   error: (401) Unauthorized.    at
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()    at
>   Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Services.Common.ServiceBusConnectClient.GetWebResponse(WebRequest
>   request)    at
>   Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Services.Common.ServiceBusConnectClient.get_WabsDeploymentAddress()
>   at
>   Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Services.Common.ServiceBusConnectClient..ctor(Uri
>   address, TimeSpan timeout, Boolean checkClient, Boolean
>   trustAllCertificate)    at
>   Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Services.Common.ServiceBusConnectClient..ctor(Uri
>   address, Boolean checkClient, Boolean trustAllCertificate)    at
>   Microsoft.ServiceBus.AFConnect.ServerExplorer.FormAddServer.ButtonOK_Click(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e)

Answer (score 0):

Finally I was able to figure this out. Hopefully this will help somebody. Here is the solution. When connecting to remote BizTalk Adapter service and your machine is not in the domain, you can use the following command to start Visual studio from a command window. Make sure that you start the command windows as administrator.

runas /netonly /user:w12r2apps\administrator "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"

Note: w12r2apps is your sever name where BizTalk Adapter Service runtime is installed. Also, make sure that the account you are using is a domain administrator or local admin on the server. Otherwise, the adapter (e.g., SQL Adapater) will not be created.